Where is the fallacy?
I'm struggling with an argument that leads to a contradiction, and yet I cannot pinpoint where the fallacy is. Help will be appreciated. Here is the argument:
Let $V$ be a normed space and $W \subset \bar{W} = V$ a proper, dense subspace. Let $E$ be a Hamel basis of $W$, and $E'$ a Hamel basis of $V$ that extends $E$: $E \subset E'$. As $W$ is proper, $E'$ is strictly larger than $E$. So, take $e \in E'\setminus E$. (I'll assume that $||e|| = 1$).
Now, take ${\cal Z} = {\textrm span}(\{e\})$, and ${\cal Y} = {\textrm span}(E'\setminus\{e\})$, so that $W \subseteq {\cal Y}$.
Also, as $V = {\cal Y} + {\cal Z}$,   and  ${\cal Y} \cap {\cal Z} = \{0\}$, every $x \in V$, can be uniquely decomposed as $x = z + y$, with $z \in {\cal Z}, y \in {\cal Y}$. Use this decomposition to define $p: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$
$$p(x=y+z) = \lVert z\rVert$$
$p$ is a seminorm in $V$, and, in particular, $p(x \in {\cal Y}) = 0$. Now, define $\varphi: {\cal Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
$$\varphi(z = c e) = c.$$
$\varphi$ is bounded, and $|\varphi(z)| = |c| =\lVert ce\rVert =  \lVert z\rVert = p(z)$. Hahn-Banach extends $\varphi$ into $\hat{\varphi}: V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with $\hat{\varphi}$ bounded, and $|\hat{\varphi}(x)| \le p(x), \forall x \in V$. In particular, for $x \in {\cal Y}$,  $|\hat{\varphi}(x)| \le p(x) = 0$, and, hence $W \subseteq {\cal Y} \subseteq \ker(\hat{\varphi})$.
But, as $\hat{\varphi}$ is bounded, $\ker\hat{\varphi}$ is closed, and hence $V = \bar{W} \subseteq\ker\hat{\varphi}$. This is of course a contradiction.

What is the statement of Hahn-Banach you're using, exactly?

Let V be a vector space over F ∈ {$\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$},
p a seminorm on it, W ⊆ V a linear subspace and φ : W → $\mathbb{C}$ a linear functional such that
|φ(w)| ≤ p(w) for all w ∈ W. Then there is a linear functional $\hat{\varphi}$ : V → $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\hat{\varphi}_{|_W}$ = φ
and |$\hat{\varphi}$(v)| ≤ p(v) for all v ∈ V .

The statement of Hahn-Banach theorem is taken from lecture notes by Prof. Mueger that I'm reading. The faulty argument that leads to a contradiction is mine. But I cannot figure out what is wrong with it.

Note that it says there is a "linear functional". It doesn't say there is a bounded linear functional relative to your original norm. So on what grounds do you assert that $\hat{\varphi}$ is "bounded" and hence that its kernel is closed?

IOW: you are invoking the Hahn-Banach Dominated Extension Theorem, which is about vector spaces, not Banach spaces. the "bounded" part of the conclusion is "bounded by $p(x)$ on $W$", not "bounded in the sense of bounded linear transformation for a Banach space". You are mis-reading the conclusion to assert that the resulting function is a bounded linear functional relative to whatever the original norm on your Banach space was, so you cannot conclude its kernel is closed relative to the original norm of your Banach space. That norm doesn't play any role here.

You're right, thanks! I unconsciously "read" that the functionals involved are bounded, and carried that mistake to an absurd conclusion. Then I couldn't pinpoint what had gone astray.  On the other hand, bounded functionals are well-defined for normed spaces, not only for Banach ones. But, thanks again.

To prevent this from going unanswered because the answer is hiding in the comments...
The Hahn-Banach Dominated Extension Theorem is about vector spaces. The conclusion is that there exists a linear functional $\hat{\varphi}$ such that $|\hat{\varphi}(x)|\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in W$. It does not conclude that there is a bounded linear functional (relative to any norm you may have in your original vector space). So there is no warrant to conclude that $\hat{\varphi}$ is a bounded functional; which means the claim that its kernel must be closed is unwarranted.
